# Type-Hints: How can I indicate that I want to return an instance of the actual class?

Tags: python, python-3.5, typing, type-hinting

When I try to combine Type Hints and object creation through
a `classmethod` I get the following `NameError`:

```
NameError: name 'Person' is not defined
```

**How can I indicate through type hinting that I want to return an 
instance of the class which I am currently defining? (see example)**

---

Example:

The definition of the `classmethod` `from_dict` fails because Python cannot resolve the `class Person`.

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(self, info: dict) -> Person:
        person_obj = Person(info['name'])
        return person_obj

    def speak(self, word: str) -> str:
        print(word)
        return self.name + 'said' + word
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [TypeVar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar).

```
from typing import TypeVar
PersonType = TypeVar("PersonType", bound="Person")

class Person:
    @classmethod
    def from_dict(self, info: dict) -> PersonType:
        person_obj = Person(info['name'])
        return person_obj
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a string:

```
@classmethod
def from_dict(self, info: dict) -> 'Person':
    person_obj = Person(info['name'])
    return person_obj
```

This makes the return type of the classmethod a Person. This is also useful when writing classes that depend on each other.